# Viewpager in Gallery dialog android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-dialog

I have List of images so how to craete dialog with viewpager and when you swipe left or right images should change I dont know how and I cant find any tutorials can you show example with adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check this link please http://androidsharper.blogspot.com/2014/08/dialog-with-view-pager.html and http://tiku.io/questions/3558818/viewpager-in-simple-dialog